# using pupeteer package from node server to launch a browser in ubuntu 18.04, the browser poped up is transparent, no any color, no any thing

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu

sample code:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
  args: ["--disable-setuid-sandbox","--no-sandbox"],
  ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--enable-automation"],
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto("http://127.0.0.1:3000/");
```

amazing appearance!!
[image]